# How to make rounded bottom of header?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How to make rounded header like this?

[image: Rounded Header]

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far so we can help you with that code?

Comment: Create a circle then overlay your header.

Comment: search here, this kind of question comes up once a week and has been answered many times ...

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check the basics, and please post code of your work, here is head start [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/0jyrtrrp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.div-inner {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  height: 120px;
}

.div-inner:before,
.div-inner:after {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 80px #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;  /* You can change it */ 
  content: '';
  right: -20%;
  left: -20%;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <div class="div-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it, he's a simple way. Have you got any HTML/CSS experience or are you new to this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #8e8e8e;
}
.header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.content {
  background: #fff;
  height: calc(100vh - 110px);
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 60px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 60px;
  padding: 60px 20px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
```